# Something like cursor or recordset iterator in Hibernate or JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cursor, recordset

Are there any means to work with long query results in Hibernate? What if I want to draw table with million of records and allow user to navigate over it?

The goal is not to transfer all data to client at the time and handle the current position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple mechanism of `FirstResult` and `MaxResults` in a Query object.

```
query.setFirstResult(5);
query.setMaxResults(5);
```

Above will fetch `5` records from fifth record.

You can use [ScrollableResults](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/ScrollableResults.html) but it will be slower compared to above one for large results.

Answer (score 3):

You may try with Hibernate [ScrollableResults](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/ScrollableResults.html), I quote:

> A result iterator that allows moving around within the results by
>   arbitrary increments. The Query / ScrollableResults pattern is very
>   similar to the JDBC PreparedStatement/ ResultSet pattern and the
>   semantics of methods of this interface are similar to the similarly
>   named methods on ResultSet.

Answer (score 1):

To improve queries with large dataset, use a keyset pagination and avoid offset pagination if possible because using an offset needs to read all data while using a keyset pagination (filter) reduces the dataset (improvements can be significant).

Here is a good article https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset